# How to kill thread that runs arbitrary client code

Tags: java, multithreading, timeout

For academical purposes (read: university course) I am building an application which loads and executes code submitted by students.

Each student submits a .class file which is loaded, instantiated via reflection and then executed within its own thread. A custom security manager is used to prohibit access to classes & methods outside of a whitelist. What is still possible though is infinite loops in student code. I would like to be able to time-out the threads running student code and I can not rely on them implementing this functionality themselves.

In java 7 I could have used Thread.kill() but this method is no longer available since java 8. I would need some other way to forcibly kill a thread running arbitrary unknown code which may contain infinite loops.

If there is some nifty trick I am not aware of, please tell me. Thanks a lot.

**Edit:**

The application is simulating a multi-agent system with students submitting implementations of an agent within the system. Interactions between agents (implemented via accessing package-private fields of a super class) should be possible without the students being required to implement some kind of command line interface. As far as I am aware this rules out running student code in a seperate process rather than a thread.

Comment: Killing threads is a pain, but killing whole processes is fairly easy. Run the student code in a fork, and use pipes to communicate results? The host process can ait on the fipe having content or time out and then kill the child process.

Comment: are you asking about Java? in Java 7 there is no `Thread.kill()` (or is it so late that I should be sleeping?), do you mean `Thread.stop()`? still available in Java 8 (and even Java 13)

Comment: `Thread.interrupt()` should help, unless student code was in the middle of `Thread.sleep()`, say, and is catching that exception... But otherwise you could run a parallel thread that sleeps for 30 seconds and call `interrupt()` if the student thread is still going

Comment: @iluxa Interrupting a thread does not guarantee it will stop. That requires cooperation from the executing code, which is unlikely when written by a malicious, or at least inexperienced, developer.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger yes, my mistake, I apologise. I meant Thread.stop(). As far as I am aware the stop() method is deprecated since Java 8 and no longer works. If I am mistaken please let me know. I edited my question with some additional information.

Comment: deprecated since Java 1.2 (Java 2; 20 years); but still working (Java 13): [Thead.stop()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#stop()) Maybe using an [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) would be better... it returns [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) which apparently can be canceled (shutdown `Executor`, never used myself, not sure how reliable it works)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Future`. Launch your students code as Future and specify timeout:

```
myFuture.get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit);
```

If it times out, catch the exception and then  cancel this Future:

```
myFuture.cancel(true);
```

Comment: Interrupting a thread does not guarantee it will stop. That requires cooperation from the executing code, which is unlikely when written by a malicious, or at least inexperienced, developer.

Comment: I researched the API and as far as I can tell the Runnable / Callable in the future needs to support being canceled. The Future API does not stop the thread outright.

Comment: `cancel` will not 9always) work, but you can `shutdownNow` the `ExecutorService` which seems to stop the threads (tried with a very simple Thread, so not that sure). Doc: "shutdownNow() method prevents waiting tasks from starting and attempts to stop currently executing tasks." (probably just calling `stop`)

Comment: @Carlos There are three public implementations of `ExecutorService` in the JDK: `ThreadPoolExecutor`, `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`, and `ForkJoinPool`. None of them call `stop()` when `shutdownNow()` is invoked. The documentation of the first two state the pool will `interrupt()` any running threads. The same cannot be said for `ForkJoinPool` but looking at the implementation it _appears_ to call `interrupt()` as well (though I haven't taken the time to properly understand the code).